# Qt, Visual Studio 2017 and .vcxproj.user Files

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017, qt5, vcxproj

I am using Visual Studio 15.9.14 and Qt 5.13.0 on multiple machines. When I check out my source from version control:

- If I open the VS IDE to build my solutions, everything compiles and links correctly.
- If I build the solutions from the command line using devenv.exe, there are multiple compile and link errors in the Qt projects.

The problem is that when building from the command line, the .vcxproj.user files are NOT generated, and therefore $QTDIR is not defined for use in my projects. The result is my automated/nightly builds fail.

I can build a tool to create the files and integrate it into my build process, but I shouldn't have to. This problem seems to be related to the VS/Qt integration. I have also encountered a similar problem in the IDE where I had to force the files to regenerate by touching the projects.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before discussing devenv, could you tell -- is it essential that you use it from the command line? Maybe `qmake proj.pro -spec win32-msvc` + `jom -j4 ...` would suffice your needs?
...and could you show the exact command line commands being used? Something like `qmake -spec win32-msvc -tp vc proj.pro` should do the trick, am I wrong?

Comment: The projects are being built as part of an automated build process run from Jenkins. There are some Qt projects, but the majority of projects - well over 200 in the main solution - are not Qt. We use devenv to build multiple solutions.

Comment: could you show your commands used for build? Is `qmake -spec win32-msvc -tp vc ` + `"%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\devenv.exe" %PWD%\..\..\%ProjName%.sln /build "Release|Win32"` not working?

Comment: That may be the problem - we have never used qmake as part of the process. The command line is like: devenv /build "Debug|Win32" /out pathtolog.log pathtosolution.sln VS 2012 has worked just fine with only that.

Comment: If you have any *.pro file subprojects, then qmake is almost probably essential, it can also generate studio solution. Studio's addin uses it anyway for that. Unless there is some complex custom build with qt's libraries linked directly (is it even possible?), you could give the classic approach a try.